# Make classes like String parcelable?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

Is there any way to make a final/closed class parcelable? E.g. `String` or `ZonedDateTime`(from `java.time`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to make a final/closed class parcelable?

No, sorry.

> E.g. String or ZonedDateTime(from java.time).

Android can already put a `String` into a `Parcel`, so there is no need somehow make it `Parcelable`.

Also, bear in mind that custom `Parcelable` classes [cannot be used in all cases](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html). I just had to deal with that particular problem this morning.

Comment: thanks, but why does `abstract class BaseDialogFragment<T: Parcelable> : DialogFragment()` and then `class MyDialogFragment : BaseDialogFragment<String>()` lead to `Type argument is not within its bounds Expected: Parcelable Found: String`?

Comment: Update: Posted a follow up question here, would be glad if you can have a look on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61462507/type-argument-is-not-within-its-bounds-expected-parcelable-found-string

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf: `String` is not `Parcelable`. My point is that `String` does not need to be `Parcelable`.