# Type argument is not within its bounds Expected: Parcelable Found: String

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, parcelable

I am creating a generic, abstract class like this:

```
abstract class BaseDialogFragment<T: Parcelable> : DialogFragment()
```

Trying to implement this class as

```
class MyDialogFragment : BaseDialogFragment<String>()
```

gives me

```
Type argument is not within its bounds Expected: Parcelable Found: String
```

for the String in `BaseDialogFragment<String>()`.

So, how can I use `String` as a value for `T`? Is my condition `T: Parcelable` somehow wrong, if I want `T`to be a parcelable type?

Comment: I'm afraid you can do that. You could however try to allow every Types at compile time, and then at runtime (inside init block) you could try validating the stuffs using shorthand inline functions like [require](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html). Edit: At runtime there's type erasure. Sorry you can't check types of generic parameters. :(

Comment: unfortunately my `T` is later on used as a generic type argument for a class that is Parcelable / parcelized using `@Parcelize`. When using `T` without conditions, I get an error.

Comment: `Type is not directly supported by 'Parcelize'. Annotate the parameter type with '@RawValue' if you want it to be serialized  using 'writeValue()'`

Comment: Yep, unfortunately you can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, how can I use String as a value for T?

You can't. `String` is not `Parcelable`, because `Parcel` already knows how to handle `String`. Similarly, you cannot use `ByteArray` for `T`, or `Int`, or `Boolean`.

Comment: it's a shame, but at least I know why ): Thanks!

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf: Yeah, the best that I can offer you is to wrap the string in a `Parcelable` type, such as a `data class` with `@Parcelize`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I passed a list by

```
val list = bundle.getParcelableArrayList<SomeClass<String>>("key") ?: listOf()
```

Make sure `SomeClass` is `Parcelable` (all it's fields are parcelable too):

```
@Parcelize
data class SomeClass<T>(
    val text: String,
    ...
) : Parcelable
```